# Secure authentication without SSL

Tags: authentication, web-applications, ssl

I'm starting to write a small web application and have started thinking about securing login (only used for administration).

If I could, I'd install a CACert or self-signed SSL certificate, since for now I'll be the only one logging in, but my host isn't too accommodating.

Are there any reasonable options for securing the site without SSL? I've been thinking about options for authentication:

1. Implement a salted hash in JavaScript. When the login page is loaded, generate a salt server-side. Send it to the client in the clear and store it in a session variable.
2. Digest authentication. I just found this idea browsing SO, and it's probably a lot more reasonable than rolling my own auth.
3. OpenID. It's an open standard, no passwords are required (and I can "hijack" my OpenID provider's SSL to add security to the login process), but I have no idea how OpenID works or how secure it is. (Needs research. For example, can an OpenID authentication be replayed?)

The problem with all of these is that:

- Sessions can be hijacked
- Only login is secure, everything else is in the clear

The only option I can think of for securing the app after login is some disgusting JavaScript and PHP sending encrypted blobs of ASCII back and forth. I don't want to do this.

Is there any encryption (for pageloads and POSTs) that can be implemented in my server-side scripting language of choice without the blessing or involvement of my host, but that would be supported by the browser? Can sessions be secured from hijacking (practically) without SSL?

What would you do in a situation like this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can securely authenticate without needing to implement protection against eavesdropping.  For example, you can prevent others from sending requests, even though they can read the contents of your requests.  If you need to protect against eavesdropping, I'd recommend just going somewhere where you can use SSL.

If you just need simple authentication without real security, your provider will probably support HTTP Basic.  This (along with a good design which limits capabilities, and backups ;) is a reasonable interim solution while you worry about other problems.

For authenticating your identity, OpenID can't be replayed.  Each authentication sequence is signed.  However, OpenID by itself only lets you establish your identity with the server.  It won't let you sign or otherwise authenticate a request.  OAuth would, but it requires transport encryption for part of the protocol.

You could sign each request with a shared secret.  This would prevent an attacker from submitting or replaying a request, but the requests themselves can still be read by an eavesdropper.  See the documentation for Amazon AWS authentication (which includes client libraries) or flickr's authentication.  The basic protocol is:

- require a timestamp (and probably a nonce) as request parameters
- normalize, sort, concatenate all request parameters
- concatenate with URI, host, verb, etc.
- hash with secret key
- send hash in header with request
- server does the same and compares signature

Comment: how to implement this what u said?

Answer (score 3):

If you're approaching this as an interesting way of playing with different authentication and encryption methods that's great, but the least expensive and most straightforward solution is to get a host where you can install a SSL cert.

Comment: Right now, an attacker would have very little to gain by breaking my app, so it's definitely an experiment.

Answer (score 1):

If you register the remote IP address in the session, it cannot be hijacked. Someone trying to use the session with a different IP address could be easily detected. PHP Sessions use that by default (and I guess it is not optionable). Simple and efficient solution.

Comment: That's a great point, but restricting a session to a single IP doesn't protect against attackers on the same network (when a session is most likely to be hijacked).

Comment: It also breaks a number of proxy situations (including BlackBerry).

Comment: And also on mobile networks your [IP can change during session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550798/can-ip-change-during-session).

Comment: @sirwilliam Not here. IP spoofing is only possible for lone packets out of context, you cannot keep a conversation with a peer using spoofed IP address, because logically when the peer answeres to the spoofed IP, the answer doesn't come back to you. That makes spoofing in TCP sessions virtually impossible, therefore you don't have to worry about that in web development at all.