# Is it secure to use file_get_contents secure for passwords, without SSL?

Tags: php, ssl

I am wondering if `file_get_contents` is secure for passwords with no SSL. I have made a admin panel in PHP and have this method for passwords instead of SQL. Please give a source for your info if possible.

Comment: Unless you encrypt / decrypt the password on either end, the password is retrieved in plain text without SSL, right ?

Comment: what kind of security are you talking about? Give a use case and tell us how you intend to solve it with ' file_get_contents()`.

Comment: well with the admin form i have a text box and a if statement that says if the box = file_get_contents("pass/pass.txt") then overwrite a webpage

Comment: So the password is still being sent across the wild and wicked interweb from client to server in plaintext.... no, that's not secure.... it makes no difference whether you verify that password against one stored in a file compared with one stored in a database; neither is secure between client and server

Comment: how can I make it secure? I know i can use encryption but can you give an example

Comment: How can you make it secure? Use SSL

Comment: My site doesn't support it :( is there like encryption i can use ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Secure authentication without SSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355952/secure-authentication-without-ssl)

Comment: how would one do this? sorry, just started coding a year ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing a plain text password in a file and reading it with `file_get_contents` will work, but your security will be low. More specifically, it will risk your users' security. This is because, even though they should not, some of them will reuse passwords across services, together with the email address that you might also be holding for them.

With that in mind, you should be hashing these passwords, and not holding them in plain text. That means that you'll convert the password to a form that cannot be reversed, and so to check the password, you'll need to hash the one the user enters at login time too. It's a clever way of making it difficult for crackers to work out what the real password actually is, even if they get into your server and steal the password file.

The recommended approach in PHP is to use `password_hash`, details for which are in the PHP manual. The advantage to this function is that it is deliberately slow, which makes it harder for a potential attacker to 'brute force' guess many millions of passwords.

When handling passwords it is also a good idea to do so via SSL, using a server certificate inside your web server. This makes it harder for MITM (man in the middle) attacks to take place, which can steal a password in transit across the network.

Comment: Thank you for this information I will be sure to update my site right away!

Comment: and could I use the sha1 function for encryption and store it in a text file?

Comment: Great, glad it was useful @Jay.

Comment: The SHA1 function will work, and is probably better than no hashing at all, but the problem is it is too fast. Modern processors can crack several million passwords a second if they are hashed with MD5, and SHA1 isn't much better. The one I mentioned in my answer is written to be deliberately slow, which makes it more secure.